How to view the complete aggregation statement when using spring data mongodb?
I just started using spring data mongodb aggregation query.
fun findRoot(): MarkdownMongoDocument? {
    val aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        MarkdownMongoDocument::class.java,
        MarkdownMongoRepositoryProperties.findRoot()
    )
    val results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, MarkdownMongoDocument::class.java) 
    return results.mappedResults[0]
}

MarkdownMongoRepositoryProperties.findRoot()
public static List<AggregationOperation> findRoot() {
        List<String> jsons = List.of(
                "{ $match: { pid: 0 } }",
                "{$graphLookup:{from:\"t_markdown\",startWith:\"$_id\",connectFromField:\"_id\",connectToField:\"pid\",depthField:\"level\",as:\"children\"}}",
                "{$unwind:{path:\"$children\",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}}",
                "{ $sort: { \"children.level\": -1 } }",
                "{$group:{_id:\"$_id\",title:{$first:\"$title\"},path:{$first:\"$path\"},pid:{$first:\"$pid\"},createUserId:{$first:\"$createUserId\"},isDirectory:{$first:\"$isDirectory\"},children:{$push:\"$children\"}}}",
                "{$addFields:{children:{$reduce:{input:\"$children\",initialValue:{level:-1,presentChild:[],prevChild:[]},in:{$let:{vars:{prev:{$cond:[{$eq:[\"$$value.level\",\"$$this.level\"]},\"$$value.prevChild\",\"$$value.presentChild\"]},current:{$cond:[{$eq:[\"$$value.level\",\"$$this.level\"]},\"$$value.presentChild\",[]]}},in:{level:\"$$this.level\",prevChild:\"$$prev\",presentChild:{$concatArrays:[\"$$current\",[{$mergeObjects:[\"$$this\",{children:{$filter:{input:\"$$prev\",as:\"e\",cond:{$eq:[\"$$e.pid\",\"$$this._id\"]}}}}]}]]}}}}}}}}",
                "{$addFields:{children:\"$children.presentChild\"}}"
                );
       return jsons.stream().map(Aggregation::stage).toList();
    }

As shown above, I did not find a way to directly convert the entire statement into List<AggregationOperation>, I can only split the entire statement.
Then I want to view the query statement processed by spring data mongodb, but the output log is omitted.
2024-05-16T15:45:07.693+08:00 DEBUG 10204 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command      : Command "aggregate" started on database "sage-dev" using a connection with driver-generated ID 3 and server-generated ID 71 to localhost:27017. The request ID is 12 and the operation ID is 11. Command: {"aggregate": "t_markdown", "pipeline": [{"$match": {"pid": 0}}, {"$graphLookup": {"from": "t_markdown", "startWith": "$_id", "connectFromField": "_id", "connectToField": "pid", "depthField": "level", "as": "children"}}, {"$unwind": {"path": "$children", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}}, {"$sort": {"children.level": -1}}, {"$group": {"_id": "$_id", "title": {"$first": "$title"}, "path": {"$first": "$path"}, "pid": {"$first": "$pid"}, "createUserId": {"$first": "$createUserId"}, "isDirectory": {"$first": "$isDirectory"}, "children": {"$push": "$children"}}}, {"$addFields": {"children": {"$reduce": {"input": "$children", "initialValue": {"level": -1, "presentChild": [], "prevChild": []}, "in": {"$let": {"vars": {"prev": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$$value.level", "$$this.level"]}, "$$value.prevChild", "$$value.presentChild"]}, "current": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$$value.level", "$$this.level"]}, "$$value.presentChild", []]}}, "in": {"level": "$$this.level", "prevChild": "$$prev", "presentChild" ...

I looked at the code of MongoTemplate and found the following line of key code, but the method is private and I cannot call it.
Document command = aggregationUtil.createCommand(collectionName, aggregation, context);

if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
    LOGGER.debug(String.format("Executing aggregation: %s", serializeToJsonSafely(command)));
}


I don’t want to set up spring’s logs anymore.
Is there a way for me to use the entire native statement directly?
How to view the converted statement of spring data mongodb?

Just help me solve one of the 2nd and 3rd questions, thanks.

You can execute the native query using the MongoTemplate#executeCommand overloaded method (takes JSON string or a org.bson.Document as parameter). Another way is to use the annotation @Aggregation (used with MongoRepository).

@prasad_  Could you post some sample code?

Here is one sample: Aggregation query for @Aggregation annotation in Spring. Get more code samples with this search string in Google: "MongoRepository @Aggregate".

@prasad_ This is not what I want. Using annotations is no different from the code I posted. They both split the entire statement.

I am not sure what you are looking for. Further you can try this from within Spring Data MongoDB using the MongoTemplate#executeCommand: Database Command - Aggregate.
